# How can I find the implementation and configuration file of PKCS#11

Tags: java, pkcs#11

I'm trying to make a program that reads and displays certificate info from the token (Safenet) 
but the problem that I face is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.ProviderException: Error parsing configuration
```

so I think the problem is in the Configuration file.

How can I make the configration file and also the implementation file so it works correctly.
Thanks

Comment: which web server did you use ? glassfish something?

Comment: do i have to use web server ? I'm using glassfish3 .

Answer (score 0):

you can able to resolve the error by correcting nss.cfg in %AS_HOME%\domains\nssdomain\config\

you can follow the instructions in the section "Configure Glassfish to Use the NSS Stores" on this [page](https://developer.connectopensource.org/display/CONNECTWIKI/Instructions+to+set+up+CONNECT+in+FIPS+mode+on+Windows+Glassfish+environment).

Either follow this link [also](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6994008).

Answer (score 0):

In order to work with `PKCS#11` in java you need to provide a config file where you at least specify library and name parameter. In this parameters you must specify the path to native library for the token and a arbitrary identifier. Additionally you can add more parameters but they are optional, you can take a look on [java pkcs#11 reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html#Config). I give you a code sample to instantiate a `PKCS#11`:

```
// create configuration
String pkcs11nativeLibrary = "/path_to_native_library/library.so";
String pkcs11ConfigSettings = "name = mySmartCard\n" + "library = " + pkcs11nativeLibrary;
byte[] pkcs11ConfigBytes = pkcs11ConfigSettings.getBytes();
final ByteArrayInputStream confStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11ConfigBytes);

// instantiate the provider with your config
SunPKCS11 pkcs11Provider = new SunPKCS11(confStream);
Security.addProvider(pkcs11Provider);

// get the keystore
Char[] pkcs11Password = "your_password".toCharArray();
KeyStore myPKCS11KS = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", pkcs11Provider );
myPKCS11KS.load(null, pkcs11Password);
```

In the sample I put the pkcs11 password directly, however when you try to load a PKCS#11 from some client you have to get the password dinamically in order to do so you can change you key store instance for something like:

```
// YourCallbackHandler must implements javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler
KeyStore.CallbackHandlerProtection cbhp = new KeyStore.CallbackHandlerProtection(new YourCallbackHandler());
KeyStore.Builder builder = KeyStore.Builder.newInstance("PKCS11", pkcs11Provider, cbhp);
KeyStore myPKCS11KS = builder.getKeyStore();
```

Hope this helps,